# How to make the parameter's "map" button turned on by default in custom Integromat app?

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

By default, my select parameter allows me to choose the value within options. To enter an ID from the previous app in the Scenario, I have to manually click on the 'map' button. How can the parameter's map mode be turned on by default?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n8kB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the line `"mode": "edit"` to your `select` object, like so:

```
{
    "name": "currencyId",
    "type": "select",
    "label": "Currency",
    "options": "rpc://listCurrencies",
    "required": true,
    "mode": "edit"
}
```

This will turn the `map` button on by default.
The [Integromat Best Practices docs](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/best-practices#remote-procedure) describe the cases in which this setting should and should not be used.